# R ggplot set origin when using a log scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

The last line in the following code sets the origin of the plot at zero for the y-scale and the y-scale's limits.  How do I do this for the x-scale when using a log10 grid?

```
breaks <- 10^(-10:10)                                      # break for major axis
minor_breaks <- rep(1:9, 21)*(10^rep(-10:10, each = 9))    # breaks for minor axis

ggplot(data = cars, aes(x = dist, y = speed)) +                    
  geom_point() +                                                   
  scale_x_log10(breaks = breaks, minor_breaks = minor_breaks) +   # use log10 scale for x  
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey50")) +
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour = "grey70")) +
  theme_light(base_size = 12) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0,30))        # sets origin and limits for y-scale
```

Comment: Given that `log10(0)` evaluates to `-Inf`, what do you imagine the origin of a log scale to be?

Comment: Let's say I would like the x minimum and maximum to be 10 and the maximum 150 - so I would like the plot origin to be 0 on the y-axis and and 10 on the x-axis (no starting gap)

Comment: Two keywords to go down the rabbit hole are *inverse hyperbolic sine* (ihs or asinh) and *hyperbolic sine* (sinh), they underlie the `scales::pseudo_log_trans()` function.   https://github.com/r-lib/scales/blob/master/R/trans-numeric.r#L254 https://stackoverflow.com/a/33612948/10276092

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using a modified transformation, `pseudo_log_trans`, which accommodates zero values (and even negatives) by smoothly transitioning between a linear scale in [-1, 1] and a signed log scale beyond that range. The approximate point of transition can be modified using the first parameter, `sigma`.

```
ggplot(data = cars, aes(x = dist, y = speed)) +                    
    geom_point() +         
    scale_x_continuous(trans = scales::pseudo_log_trans(1)) +
    theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey50")) +
    theme(panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour = "grey70")) +
    theme_light(base_size = 12) +
    coord_cartesian(expand = FALSE,   # EDIT #2
                    xlim = c(0, 130), ylim = c(0, 30))
```

[image]

Here's how it transitions between the linear and log scales:

```
plot(scales::pseudo_log_trans(), xlim = c(-5, 10))
lines(scales::log_trans(), xlim = c(-5, 10), col = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: The duel purpose of the line   "scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0,30)) " was toset preclude that gap a the origin as well as at the maximum - not sure how you do this with a log scale ... ggplot seems to like to have these gaps, which is mostly ok but not for the particular purpose I'm trying to achieve with real data

Comment: `coord_cartesian` has an `expand` argument too, so you can control the default padding that ggplot places around the data that way, too. Edited the answer above to show an example.

Comment: Jon your edit seems to work with the "scale_x_log10" approach ... at least to get the result that I'm seeking. However, it does report a few warnings to the console.  Interestingly I get the same warnings when using "scale_x_continuous(trans = scales::pseudo_log_trans(1))".  Assistance is much appreciated!

Comment: The warning is saying that the version of `expand` in `coord_cartesian` is TRUE/FALSE rather than a two-element numeric vector like the `expand` parameter inside `scale_x_continuous`. So I should have put in `FALSE` there -- updated my answer accordingly.